# Under what circumstances, if any, will the result of reading /proc/cpuinfo change?

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu, proc

What I understand so far is that when a program opens and reads any file under `/proc/`, the kernel will generate the information on the fly. In the specific case of `cpuinfo` most of that data is determined by hardware and obviously is not going to change while the system is running. What I am not sure of is whether *all* of that data *cannot* change while the system is running.

Is it possible for any of the values returned from `/proc/cpuinfo` to be changed without the system having to be restarted?

Comment: CPU speed information will change, if CPU power saving settings are enabled

Comment: Interesting. What are you trying to store the information periodically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. For one thing, the `cpu MHz` field will change very often since it shows the *current* speed of your CPU. For example, on my system:

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do grep -m 1 MHz /proc/cpuinfo ; done
cpu MHz     : 1596.000
cpu MHz     : 1596.000
cpu MHz     : 1596.000
cpu MHz     : 1596.000
cpu MHz     : 2394.000
cpu MHz     : 2394.000
cpu MHz     : 1596.000
cpu MHz     : 1596.000
cpu MHz     : 2394.000
cpu MHz     : 2394.000
```

The command above will print the `cpu MHz` line of my first CPU 10 times. As you can see above, that resulted in 2 separate values, and this without even adding any wait time. You can expect this field to change very often. I don't think any of the other values are likely to change and none did in my tests but I can't swear to that.

Answer (score 3):

It is architecture dependent - the relevant code is here (for ARM):

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kernel/setup.c#L1074

Note: for ARM, it appears that all fields should remain constant after they are computed - there is no `cpu MHz` (referenced by @terdon for his answer on his architecture).

For example, here is the output on a Raspberry Pi:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 38.40
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 5

processor   : 1
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 38.40
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 5

processor   : 2
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 38.40
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 5

processor   : 3
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 38.40
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 5

Hardware    : BCM2709
Revision    : a01041
Serial      : 000000002489fe23
```